# PDF Markup and Annotation Tool

Tags: android, pdf, annotations

Hello Fellow Developers,

I am developing a PDF annotation for Android Tablet and would like to open/display PDF file within my android application to edit. I have done research on how to open PDF file and most methods and libraries suggest to convert the PDF to a image file. I don't want to convert to image file because the image file pixelate when I increase resolution. Now the problem I am facing are.

1) Which method I must use to display the pdf file within my application to annotate
2) I also want to implement text reflow in my app

Please suggest.

Thank you.

Regards,
Marcello

Answer (score 0):

If you will read pdf file specification, you will find, that pdf have no any type of flow. Actually each letter just is strictly coordinated on a page. Therefore:

1. It is simple to annotate any content of pdf document by the coordinates the mark on an any rendering content.
2. It is impossible to use pdf as a "what you see is what you get" editor. Even it is impossible to perfectly correct parse pdf to editable and back. It is the basically WRONG idea to do, because PDF is just the representation, not the design.
3. Funniest part of the pdf is text. Especially - unicode text. I want to say, that catching non-english text from the pdf file will return unpredictable results.

Thank you!